If $a \in \mathbb{C}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, determine the minimal polyn of $\sqrt{a}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ when $\sqrt{a} \notin \mathbb{Q}(a)$
This exercise is broken down into parts:

I first proved that $\sqrt{a}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Given that $a \in \mathbb{C}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, let $m_a(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then, letting $f(x)=m_a(x^2) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ we get $f(\sqrt{a})=0$. Therefore, $\sqrt{a}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.

We are asked to determine the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{a}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ when $\sqrt{a} \notin \mathbb{Q}(a)$. (I believe that such $m_a(x^2)$ is indeed the minimal polynomial, so I would like to prove that it is irreducible of least degree over $\mathbb{Q}$).

Since $\sqrt{a} \notin \mathbb{Q}(a)$, then $x^2-a$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(a)$
Now, $m_a(x^2)=(x^2-a)p(x)\in \mathbb{Q}(a)$, and then $deg(m_a(x))=deg(p(x))$. I would like to use that last statement to prove that $m_a(x^2)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, but I do not know how to continue. Also, do I have to check that it has the least degree?

Finally, I need to determine the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{a}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ when $\sqrt{a} \in \mathbb{Q}(a)$.

For this last part, I only now that $m_a(x^2)=(x-\sqrt{a})(x+\sqrt{a})p(x)\in \mathbb{Q}(a)$.
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Show that if $\sqrt a\in\mathbb Q(a)$ then $\mathbb Q(\sqrt a)=\mathbb Q(a).$

There are infinitely many numbers in $\Bbb{Q}$ alone, so [tag:finite-fields] was not an appropriate tag. Check out tag descriptions before using them.

Since $\sqrt{a} \notin \mathbb{Q}(a)$, the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{a}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(a)[x]$ is $x^{2} - a$. Thus, $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}) : \mathbb{Q}(a)] = 2$, so $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 2[\mathbb{Q}(a) : \mathbb{Q}]$. This means that the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{a}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $2\deg(m_{a})$.
